# mvrnorm & riwish

Tags: c++, r, rinside

I would like to sample from a multivariate normal and inverse-wishart distribution. I know R has mvrnorm (MASS) and riwish (MCMCpack). Is it possible through RInside to use those functions?

Comment: phrasing in English? what are you talking about????

Comment: @slashmais: It looks pretty clear to me (if you are familiar with the relevant technology).

Comment: Added 'r' tag as well to give this a bit more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.  You can always post on rcpp-devel for more help --- the list archives show how to access different R functions from C++ via Rcpp, and RInside lets you have this from C++.